# ReactiveMongo Aggregate with Cursor

Tags: mongodb, scala, aggregation-framework, reactivemongo

I'm trying to perform a ReactiveMongo `aggregate` call with a cursor, to avoid the Result Size [restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#result-size-restrictions).

```
def sumPerUser(appId: String, date: DateTime): Future[Seq[UserImpressionSums]] = {
import collection.BatchCommands.AggregationFramework._

collection.aggregate(
  Match(BSONDocument(APP_ID -> appId, DATE_CREATED -> BSONDocument("$gte" -> BSONDateTime(date.getMillis)))),
  List(Project(BSONDocument(USER -> 1, DATE_CREATED -> 1, IP -> 1, CAMPAIGN_ID -> 1, "imp" -> BSONDocument("$literal" -> 1) )),
    Group(BSONDocument(USER -> "$user", IP -> "$ip", CAMPAIGN_ID -> "$campaign_id"))
    ("totalImps" -> SumField("imp"), DATE_CREATED -> First(DATE_CREATED)),
    Sort(Ascending(DATE_CREATED))
  ), false, true, Some(Cursor(100)))

  .map(_.result[UserImpressionSums])
}}
```

The code compiles correctly, but throws an exception on execution:

```
reactivemongo.api.commands.bson.DefaultBSONCommandError: CommandError[code=14, errmsg=cursor field must be missing or an object, doc: {
  ok: BSONDouble(0.0),
  errmsg: "cursor field must be missing or an object",
  code: BSONInteger(14)
}]
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you first try the aggregate pipeline in the MongoDB shell?

Comment: Yes, it works nicely in the MongoDB shell

Comment: Could you try without the cursor option? I guess there is a serialisation issue about it. In casd it works w/o. Please create an issue on the bug tracker.

Comment: Yes it works without the the cursor option

Comment: Please add a ticket on: https://github.com/reactivemongo/reactivemongo/issues

Comment: Here we are: https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/issues/444

Comment: See [collection.aggregate1](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/driver/src/main/scala/api/collections/genericcollection.scala#L520) in 0.12.0-SNAPSHOT